# PHP Regex Not Matching Desired Substrings

Tags: php, regex

I've written the next regular expression

```
$pattern = "~\d+[.][\s]*[A-Z]{1}[A-Za-z0-9\s-']+~";
```

in order to match substrings as `2.bon jovi - it's my life`

the problem is the only part that is recognized is - `bon jovi`
none " - " or " ' " are recognized by this regular expression.

I'd prefer to know what is wrong with the regular expression that I've wrote rather than getting a new one.

Comment: what do you need exactly, get that substring from where?

Comment: you NEVER have to use `{1}` that's implied

Answer (score 0):

A better regular expression to handle that would be...

```
$pattern = "~\d+\.\s*[\pL\pP\s]+~";
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/H2bwsj).

This will match a number, followed by a `.`, followed by optional whitespace, followed by one or more Unicode letters, whitespace or punctuation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expressions states that after the period character (can be changed to `\.`), you will have zero or more white space characters which should then be followed by 1 *upper case* letter. In your string, you do not have any upper case letters.

Secondly, the `-` should be placed last when you want to match it. So, changing your regex to this: `~\d+[.][\s]*[A-Z]{1}[A-Za-z0-9\s'-]+~` will match something like so: `2.Bon jovi - it's my life`.

On the other hand, you can change it to this: `~\d+[.][\s]*[A-Za-z0-9\s'-]+~` to match something like so: `2.bon jovi - it's my life`.

EDIT: Ammended as per the comments of Marko D and aleation.

Comment: `~` is a [regex delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) in php

Comment: in PCRE you need delimiters. normally they use "/pattern/" but you can actualy use whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = "~\d+\..*~";    
$string = "2.bon jovi - it's my life";
preg_match($pattern, $string, $match);

print_r($match);
```

output: Array ( [0] => 2.bon jovi - it's my life )

Answer (score 0):

Your regrex is as follows.

```
~                 // delimiter
\d+               // 1 or more numbers
[.]               // a period
[\s]*             // 0 or more whitespace characters
[A-Z]{1}          // 1 upper case letter
[A-Za-z0-9\s-\']+ // 1 or more characters, from the character class
~                 //delimiter
```

Comparing that to the string "2.bon jovi" You have:

```
~                 //
\d+               // "2"
[.]               // "."
[\s]*             // ""
[A-Z]{1}          // <- NO MATCH
[A-Za-z0-9\s-\']+ // 
~                 //
```

"bon" does not start with a captial letter, it therefore does not match `[A-Z]{1}`

### Cleaner regex

There are a few simple things you can do to clean up your regex

- don't use character-classes for one character
- don't specify `{1}` it's the same as not being present

Applying the above to your existing regex you get:

```
$pattern = "~\d+\.\s*[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9\s-']+~";
```

Which is slightly easier to read.

Comment: `[.] // any single character` --> Nope. It matches literal `.`

Answer (score 0):

So the way I understand this regular expression is:

```
\d+      // Match any digit, 1 or more times  
[.]      // Match a dot  
[\s]*    // Match 0 or more whitespace characters  
[A-Z]{1} // Match characters between an UPPERCASE A-Z Range 1 time  
[A-Za-z0-9\s-']+ // Match characters between A-Z, a-z, 0-9, whitespace, dashe and apostrophe
```

So straight away, your 'bon jovi' might not get matched as it's lower case and you're only looking for uppercase characters. 'bon jovi' also contains a space so perhaps changing that part of the regular expression to allow for lowercase characters and whitespace might help so you'd end up with:

```
$pattern = "~\d+[.][\s]*[A-Za-z\s]{1}[A-Za-z0-9\s-']+~";
```

Note: I quickly tested this on RegExr ( http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ ) and it appeared to match the string fine.

Comment: It is always better to test the regex in the tester written for the same language. (RegExr is ActionScript 3 regex). Most of the cases, the result will be the same, but there might be incompatibility in different implementation, which requires the right tester to reveal.

Answer (score -1):

Your `[A-Z]{1}` sub-pattern requires one capital letter, so `"2.bon jovi - it's my life"` will not match.

And you need to escape the `-` in the `[A-Za-z0-9\s-']` character class, or put it at the start or end, otherwise it is specifying a range.

```
"~\d+\.[A-Za-z0-9\s'-]+~"
```

As pointed out in the comments, it is actually not necessary to escape the `-` in the character class in your regex. That is only because you happened to precede it with a metacharacter `\s` that cannot be part of a range. Normally, if you want to match a literal `-` and you have it in a character class, you must escape it or position it as described above.

Comment: `-` is interpreted as literal `-` in the case of `[A-Za-z0-9\s-']` by PCRE. It is not necessary to escape `-` in this case, but we usually do it just to be sure.